# Проблемы Nginx + php-fpm, Docker

Tags: nginx, docker, php-fpm, php-nginx

Настроил связку Nginx + php-fmp в Docker контейнерах. Есть контейнер nginx который переадресует все запросы на обработку php файлов к контейнеру php-fpm, и это работает. Но есть одно но.

Сейчас у меня версия php-fpm 8.3, которая слушает порт 9000 не прокидывая его наружу, они работают в одной сети. Соответственно nginx отправляет запрос на `<container_name>:9000` и получает ответ. Есть один нюанс, который хорошо описан в [данной посте](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29905953/how-to-correctly-link-php-fpm-and-nginx-docker-containers). Суть в следующем: мы должны сделать bind файловой системы не только на nginx с передачей последнему ряд каталогов откуда nginx будет искать запрашиваемые ресурсы, но и сделать тоже самое в php-fpm (продублировать по сути).

Итак вопрос: если я подниму еще php7.2-fpm и php7.4-fpm в качестве отдельных сервисов с портами 9001 и 9002 соответственно, то кол-во ресурсов по объему будет таким большим из-за шаринга файлов (сайтов может быть 20+), что он мне просто отъест весь диск?

Есть вариант мб поднять их в том же сервисе, но как я понимаю их нельзя будет запустить на этапе сборке контейнера и запускать их придется постоянно из CMD, так?

Мб есть еще какие идеи? Спасибо